# How do I extract a certain amount of lines after a pattern in perl?

Tags: file, perl

Lets say I have a text file:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Target Name1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Target Name2
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
```

I want to be able to search for a target pattern (there could be multiple in the text file like in example above) and then print out a certain amount of lines that is following it. Lets say 3 lines. So then the output I would want is

```
Target Name1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5

Target Name2
Line 7 
Line 8
Line 9
```

So far all I have is code to find the target and print it out:

```
use strict;
use warning;
open (my $INFILE, $input_file);
my $outfile = "output.txt";
open (my $OUTFILE, '>', $outfile);

my $name;

while (my $line = <$INFILE>) {
  if ($line =~ m#TARGET\s+(\S+)#){
    $name = $1;
    print $OUTFILE "Target $name\n";
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to print out the next 3 lines following Target. Note: Assume that the targets are always farther apart than 3 lines from each other. I think I would need a counter right?

Answer (score 4):

A basic way is to use a flag and a counter, for when to start and how much to print. One way:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $how_many = 3;

my $to_print = 0;    
while (<>) { 
    $to_print = 1+$how_many  if /Target\s+\S+/;

    print if $to_print-- > 0;
}
```

This uses one variable to control operation, set to the number of lines to print (plus one) whenever the "trigger" is seen and then counted down with each print.  It makes some assumptions.

The [`<>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)
reads lines from files given on the command line (or from `STDIN`) so run the script by passing filenames as arguments when it is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

Skip lines until you reach the target line, then output that line. Inside the loop, read the number of lines you want and output those. Here's one way to do that:

```
while( <> ) {
    next unless /\ATarget\s+\S+/;  # skip until you find the start line
    print;                         # output the current line

    print scalar <> for 1 .. 3;    # output the next lines
    print "\n";                    # separate groups
    }
```

Comment: How would this handle two consecutive lines of `Target something`?

Comment: If you have a question about a different format, ask a new question :)

Comment: :) ok, I didn't see the `Note:` part at the very end of the question.

Comment: ...except the last one it seems

Answer (score 1):

Same solution in slightly different code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $how_many = 3;
my $pattern = qr/Target Name\d/;

while(<DATA>) {
    next unless /$pattern/;
    print;
    my $count = $how_many;
    while( $count-- > 0 ) { print scalar <DATA> }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
Line 1
Line 2
Target Name1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Target Name2
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
```

Output

```
Target Name1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5

Target Name2
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Other variation of previously posted code snippet

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $how_many = 3;
my $pattern = qr/Target Name\d/;

while(<DATA>) {
    next unless /$pattern/;
    print;
    print scalar <DATA> for 1..$how_many;
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
Line 1
Line 2
Target Name1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Target Name2
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
```

Output

```
Target Name1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5

Target Name2
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^Target\b/ and $l=$. or $. <= 3+$l&&$l' sample.txt
```

This exploits that the special Perl variable `$.` has the current line number of the input.

If you're using Gnu/Linux or a similarly reasonable OS, then the `grep` command with a trailing context of 3 lines after matches is also an alternative. If you can bear to have `--` separation lines between the matches:

```
grep -A3 Target sample.txt
grep -A3 '^Target ' sample.txt
grep -A3 -P '^Target\b' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Later edit, after reading a bit more documentation:

```
perl -ne 'print if $s = /Target/ ... $s == 2; print "\n" if $s == 3' sample.txt
```

range operator:

```
~# perl -ne 'print if (($l = $.) && /Target/) .. $. == $l+2; print "\n" if  $. == $l+2' sample.txt
Target Name1
Line 3
Line 4

Target Name2
Line 7
Line 8
```

Note: This is just some academic exercise kind of answer, I don't recommend using this, it's too cumbersome. I just wanted to see if it can be done, and when done I just posted it maybe someone would find it interesting. [zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60293026/939457)`s answer is the way to go.

Note: according to the documentation [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) `..` even if it't behaves differently in scalar context, it doesn't have a special name, it's still a range operator. However some people like to call it flip-flop. I always associated it with line-range, and that's the name I use.

Comment: That only looks like the range operator. It's the "flip flop" operator that uses exactly the same characters :)